# How to convert a JDE date into a SQL date within a stored proceedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have been working on this for several days and tried all the options I could find.  I am hoping that someone can clear this up.  Within a stored proceedure I am pulling data from JDE into a SQL table.   One of the fields is a JDE date field and I need this to go into a SQL table in the datetime format.   The date field is IVEFTJ.

I have the follwoing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM OPENQUERY(GDCJDE9PRODR, '
    SELECT 
       IVLITM,
       IVCITM,
       IVEFTJ,
       Convert(datetime,DATEADD(day,[IVEFTJ]-729960,Convert(datetime,"1900-01-01")),103) as BCDAte
FROM 
    PRODDTA.F4104
WHERE
    IVXRT = ''UP'' 
')
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** --- **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a query language used by many database systems - but SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: what kind of date format your JDE is using - cyymmdd, julian, 6 digits numeric, DATE, etc.. ?

Comment: Okay - consider myself told off.   According to the SQL server management Studio help this is SQL server 2005.   Fairly new to these forums, not enjoying being yelled at.

Comment: I believe the JDE date format is Julian e.g. sample is 111001 or 112160.   Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the SQL functions inside the openquery SQL statement, as this statement is relevant to the database you are selecting rows from. Rather, use the functions in the outer SQL statement, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   IVLITM,
   IVCITM,
   IVEFTJ,
   dateadd(day, convert(int, substring(IVEFTJ, 4, 3)), convert(datetime,convert(varchar(4), convert(int, substring(IVEFTJ, 1, 1))*100 + 1900 + convert(int, substring(IVEFTJ, 2, 2))) + '-01-01 00:00:00', 121)) as BCDAte 
FROM OPENQUERY(GDCJDE9PRODR, '
SELECT 
   IVLITM,
   IVCITM,
   IVEFTJ,
   IVEFTJ
FROM 
PRODDTA.F4104
WHERE
IVXRT = ''UP'' 
')
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6662) for you to play with

Comment: Thanks - I understand the rational above but I am getting an error "Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused overflow."   I have semi built around it by bringing the data in and then doing an update with more code in a store proccedure.   Would be good to get it working direct though.

Comment: I just assumed that your Convert(datetime,DATEADD(day, IVEFTJ-729960,Convert(datetime,"1900-01-01")),103) was right. It wasn't. You need to fix it. A quick look at it confirmed it and prompted me to go to sqlfiddle and generate a simple statement for you. I have edited my original answer. I hope it will help you

Comment: stunning thanks a million you have restored my faith in the process.

Comment: I think I have it - check the tick above?